# mysql join gets no response

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables, `donaTypes` and `fullInfo`.

`fullInfo`:

```
id          funddesc        giftamt        giftdate
001        annual fund       50.00          2010-03-09
223        alumni fund       25.00          2009-03-06
334        capital exp      100.00          2011-09-27
...            ...            ...               ...
```

`donaTypes`:

```
   id           donaType
    1          annual fund
    2          capital exp
    3          alumni fund
```

I'm trying to match up where `fullInfo.funddesc = donaTypes.donaType` with the hope of inserting the `donaTypes.id` number into the `fullInfo` table.  Here's my code but I just get a blank response (no error):

```
SELECT st1.funddesc, st2.donatype
FROM 

(select t1.funddesc
from fullInfo as t1) st1

inner join

(select t2.donatype
from donatTypes as t2) st2

on trim(st1.funddesc) like trim(st2.donaType)
;
```

I also tried :

```
SELECT t1.funddesc, t2.donatype 
FROM fullInfo as t1, 
donatTypes as t2
where trim(t1.funddesc) = trim(t2.donatype);
```

Ideally, I'd like `fullInfo` to look like this:

`fullInfo`:

```
id          funddesc        giftamt        giftdate
001             1            50.00          2010-03-09
223             3            25.00          2009-03-06
334             2           100.00          2011-09-27
...            ...            ...               ...
```

Comment: Have you verified the datatypes are the same between funddesc and donatype?

Comment: Should work, are the data types and same.   Is it possible some non-visible characters exist (CR/LF for example).   I would suggested getting the length() of the two fields from each table to make sure the text contains what you think it does.

Comment: try removing all white spaces: replace(t1.funddesc, ' ', '') = replace(t2.donatype, ' ', '')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep it a bit simpler til you get it debugged. You don't need the nested queries.  And, LIKE is not really very good for joins, because it can be kind of promiscuous.

```
SELECT fi.funddesc, dt.donaType
  FROM  fullinfo fi
  JOIN donatTypes dt on trim(fi.funddesc) = trim(dt.donaType)
```

You may also want to do this sort of thing on your two tables just to figure out what kind of stuff you actually have in your join columns.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), concat('>>>',TRIM(funddesc),'<<<') 
  FROM fullinfo 
 GROUP BY concat('>>>',TRIM(funddesc),'<<<')
```